# Javascript to change element property based on user input

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I take the number of square the user wants, then calculate the size of each square (so that they all fit in the container.)

I then define `var square` as in the 3rd line of code. I find this string pasting technique very hard to read and error-prone. The general question is thus: Is there a better way to define an element using user input?

```
var genGrid = function(num_square) {
    var square_size = ($(".grid_container").height() / num_grid) + "px";
    var square = "<div class='square' style='height:" + square_size + ";\
        width: " + square_size + "'></div>";

    $("body").append($(square));
};
```

Comment: Where does `num_square` come in?

Comment: num_square is from user input due to a prompt

Comment: It's not used anywhere in the function..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already stated passing an HTML string is not the best way to create a new DOM element. You can create a new one using plain Javascript, like this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

and together with few changes to your code, function could look similar to this:

```
function generateGrid(numGrid) {
    var squareSize = $('.grid_container').height() / numGrid;
    var $square = $(document.createElement('div')); // we create and fetch a new element

    // here come some handy methods from jQuery, please check'em out on jquery.com
    $square.width(squareSize).height(squareSize).addClass('square');
    $('.grid_container').append($square);
}

generateGrid(4);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Oh, the reason why I did not define `$square` as an element is because I have to append square multiple times. Can I just do `var square = "(document.createElement('div'))"` then?

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle for you so you can play with the code. As you can see I've splitted this problem into two functions. One of them simply builds a square element and second one is responsible for drawing a grid. Just take a look:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/cv9JA/11/)